# Alternate of Arrays

Tags: matlab

Dear I am trying to get a solution of one of my problem. I have to work with 15 variables, whose results will be produced iteratively. I have to store the result of each iteration for each variable. I will run my program under two loops. One would be inner loop and the other would be outer loop. In inner loop,  I will store the results of each iteration for 12 out of 15 variables, say in arrays,  and then for outer loop, I will also save the results for remaining 3 variables. In simple way, I can do this with the help of arrays. but I don't want to introduce so many arrays. Can you suggest me, Is it possible to do with structure or CellArrays? I would be very thankful if you write a small program under the above mention structure.  I can add a small example of my code as

```
X1 = zeros(a,1);
X2 = zeros(a,1);
X3 = zeros(a,1);  
X4 = zeros(a,1);  
X5 = zeros(a,1);  
X6 = zeros(a,1);  
X7 = zeros(a,1);  
X8 = zeros(a,1);  
X9 = zeros(a,1);  
X10 = zeros(a,1);  
X11 = zeros(a,1);  
X12 = zeros(a,1);  
X13 = zeros(b,1);  
X14 = zeros(b,1);  
X15 = zeros(b,1);  

   for i = 1:b  
       for j = 1: a   
           X1(i)= some calculation  
           X2(i) = some calculation  
           ...... and so on till   
           X12(i) = some calculation  
       end
    x13(j)=some calculation  
   X14(j)= some calculation
    X15(j) = some calculation
end
```

and at the end I want to show the results in the form of table. Is it possible to convert this into structure/cellarray?

Comment: As always, a written description of the code is far less meaningful than some actual code.  Do you have any actual code to support this question?

Comment: Learn to work with arrays. They are your friend. Especially in Matlab, where technically speaking, all variables are arrays anyway.

Comment: I can give a small example of my code

Comment: You could have a look at [Maps](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/containers.mapclass.html) to store data.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the first 12 arrays share the same length, so you can put them in one matrix, where the colums of the matrix are your arrays, and the same for the last 3 arrays

```
x1 = zeros(a,12);
x2 = zeros(b,3);

for i = 1:a
    for k = 1:12 
        x1(i,k) = i+k; %// do something else
    end
end
for i = 1:b
    for k = 1:3 
        x2(i,k) = i+k; %// do something else
    end
end
```

**EDIT**: You can also do it with a struct defined by

```
a = 5; b = 4; S = struct('x1',zeros(a,1),'x2',zeros(a,1),'x15',zeros(b,1));

S = 

     x1: [5x1 double]
     x2: [5x1 double]
    x15: [4x1 double]
```

That you can modify with that:

```
>> S.x2(3) = 3+3;
```

And you can plot like that

```
>> S.x2

ans =

     0
     0
     6
     0
     0
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good way...but I have to pass the individual arrays to different functions for different calculation.In the form of array, I can give them a name, so can remember. but in matrix form, it would be  difficult to remember the column name for me. and further, one loop will work under the other loop. So both loop can not be separated in my problem.